# Does NW.js send "crash reports" to Google (or anyone external) by default?

Tags: privacy, browser, javascript, chromium

https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/

> **crash_report_url**

> Once the app crashed, the crash dump file and information about the runtime environment will be sent to the crash server. It’s sent in the same way as in Chromium browser: a HTTP POST request with multipart/form-data as the content type. In theory, any breakpad/crashpad server could handle the request, since breakpad/crashpad work in the same way in NW as they do in Chromium.

Nothing is said about any default value/behaviour. I get the gut feeling that, by default, if a NW.js application crashes, it sends a bunch of data ("crash report") to some Chromium (= Google) server.

Can somebody please verify that this is/isn't the case? And what should I set this value to in order for it to never happen?

I don't want any data to leave my NW.js application for any reason unless I very explicitly tell it to.

PS: I would ask on their Github repo if Github allowed me to register/ask. Which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The Chromium here refers to the format of the crash report rather than the default server URL. If you do not use the [`crash_report_url`](https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/References/Manifest%20Format/#crash_report_url) field in your manifest file, NW.js will not send reports anywhere, but you can still [find the minidump files](https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Understanding%20Crash%20Dump/#find-minidump-file) on their default path on disk.

To verify this behaviour you could monitor your network traffic while using the `App.crashBrowser()` to [trigger crash for testing](https://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Developers/Understanding%20Crash%20Dump/#find-minidump-file).